# failed to rename rospack cache

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running the AR drone drivers and teleop package from Brown University's repository and I keep getting this error when I run the driver:

```
[rospack] Error: failed  to rename cache file /home/ubuntu/.ros/.rospack_cache.SBalWf to /home/ubuntu/.ros/rospack_cache: No such file or directory
```

This error started showing up recently as it was running earlier. I am running Ubuntu 11.04 off a USB stick which has about 200MB of free space remaining. I was wondering if this was due to space running low on the disk, not sure. Looked around for help but could not find this error posted online. Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10286/failed-to-rename-rospack-cache/) by [LJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/705/lj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-06-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks guys. I don't think that I would be able to rename the files myself as the ROS package is creating them plus others when I do a rosrun. I tried the rosclean purge without any success. Just going to put the drive image on a larger drive and see if that resolves the issue. The current drive will crash inevitably. Will report back.

---

Originally posted by [LJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/705/lj/) with karma: 26 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-17**:
FYI, better to give additional info updates by either updating your question, or posting comments under your question or under answers you are replying to. Posting comments as answers if frowned upon.